# How to change table prefixes in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

So I have a host which provides me with phpMyAdmin. I run phpBB and would like to change some of the table prefixes.

**How can I do this without phpMyAdmin?**

I messaged my host and they said I couldn't do it in there. Is there a sql client I can do it with and, if so, how?

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer is here:  [ Renaming prefixes of table names within phpmyadmin ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012776/renaming-prefixes-of-table-names-within-phpmyadmin

Comment: there are tons of sql clients. if you are on linux use mysql command it is very self-explanatory. If you are on windows, download something like HeidiSQL.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with phpMyAdmin.

Go to `Structure` page of the database that contains these tables.
Check the checkboxes in front of each of the tables you want to rename. 
From `With selected` dropdown chose `Replace table prefix`.
Enter current prefix in `From` field and new prefix in `To` field and press submit.

Comment: Which version of phpMyAdmin are you using?